# How to set up permissions while using dso as PHP handler?

Tags: files

I'm having all kinds of troubles while setting up my site online. I can't upload new modules and if I try caching this is what I get:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://filedwZLkV) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1900 of /home/brighton/public_html/includes/file.inc).
The file could not be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fileLbErlU) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1900 of /home/brighton/public_html/includes/file.inc).
The file could not be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://filehy4XmT) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1900 of /home/brighton/public_html/includes/file.inc).
The file could not be created.
Notice: Undefined index: search_api_page_search_form_search in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 760 of /home/brighton/public_html/includes/form.inc).
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'search_api_page_search_form_search' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 795 of /home/brighton/public_html/includes/form.inc).
```

The problem is that I have to use dso with my LAMP stack, so there's a lot of things that belong to the user "nobody" (there's no www-data user), and I'm really not quite sure how I should handle this.

A few details about the site's structure and current permissions:

Site root:

```
drwxr-x--- 12 brighton nobody       4096 Sep 12 18:55 public_html/
```

sites/default:

```
drwxr-x---  3 brighton nobody 4096 Sep 12 18:48 default/
```

sites/default/files:

```
drwxrws--- 11 brighton nobody  4096 Sep 15 12:42 files/
```

Private file system path and temporary directory (../tmp/drupal/):

```
drwxrw-rw-  3 apache   apache   4096 Sep 12 19:50 drupal/
```